# Android TV app not showing in Android TV's (version 4.4) play store even app min sdk set to 17

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my android TV app having min sdk 17, compile and target sdk 28. It is available in android TV play store of version 9 but it is not available in android TV play store of version 4.4. When I run the app by using apk file in android TV 4.4 it is working fine. Why it is not available in play store of android version 4.4?

Comment: App not showing in playstore on MiTV Stick and displays that "App is Not Compatible with this device". The app's Android manifest has "<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>" AND "<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" 
        android:required="true" />".

Comment: hi, @PawanJain i am already done this code but still not able to search my tv app on playstore

Comment: Enable it in Play console as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595856/android-tv-app-cant-be-installed-on-android-tv-devices/69777175#69777175