# Android TV app can't be installed on Android TV devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

I have already published app on Google Play Store. It can't be found in Google Play Store app on any device running Android TV which I tried. I can find it on Google Play by using its name, but there it can't be installed on my Android TV devices. There are 649 marked as supported devices in the Play Console for this app. I have even one device marked as supported on my device list. It is Google Chromecast Google TV. But it is also not compatible and I can't install my app also on this device. Does anyone experience something like this in the case of Android TV app?

Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:banner="@mipmap/icon_androidtv"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon_androidtv"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@mipmap/icon_androidtv">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Yes, my app is soo simple. There is only one view with a single WebView on it. And of course, the app can be installed on any Android TV device directly from Android Studio. Should I change something in the AndroidManifest to make it compatible with Android TV devices?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For distribution to Android TV devices, you need to opt-in within Google Play. In the Play Console, go to the Setup section within the Release grouping in the left hand menu. Select Advanced settings and switch to the Release types tab. Click "+ Add release type" and select Android TV. You have to include the required screenshots and banner for TV distribution.

Note that Android TV requires an additional review to validate [TV App Quality](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tv-app-quality).

Comment: Actually, I've added extra screenshots and a TV banner but I've missed marking the checkbox "Opt-in to Android TV" in the second step of the scenario which you mentioned. That's why I was able to publish my app and it was not available for devices running Android TV. Thanks to you I've rechecked this setting and found the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

[image]

In the current play console this is how it looks, the steps described by Ian

EDIT: Thanks to @Israr - "Now, the Word Release Types has been changed to Form Factors."

Comment: You are a lifesaver!!!!!! :))))

Comment: I did these steps already, and uploaded a build (unreviewed), but when I tap on "Install" from the test playstore, it says it's not compatible with my Chromecast TV (although last generation).

Comment: It should install once the Android TV status changes from "In review" to "Available" after successful review for TV compliance by the Google Play Team.

Comment: Now, the Word `Release Types` has been changed to `Form Factors`.